# Discord.js - Detect when message is send

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im trying to detect when someone sends an message with this code. Sadly its not working for some reason. It should give an output in the console and send an reply but both doesnt happen.

```
const bot= new CommandClient(`Bot ${token}`, { intents: ['guilds'], maxShards: 'auto',restMode: true })

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    message.reply('This is a reply!')
    .then(() => console.log("test"))
    .catch(console.error);
})
```

The **const bot** works with interaction so its probably not the problem.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very good explanation of behavior. What *is* it doing? What are you expecting it to do? Are there any error messages? If so what are they and which lines are they coming from?

Comment: I edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Try to use ```new Client``` instead ```new CommandClient```

Comment: when i try **new Client** I get the following error message in the console:
`ReferenceError: Client is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client({intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent]})

bot.on('messageCreate', async message => {
message.reply("This is a reply!")
    .then(() => console.log("test"))
    .catch(console.error);

})
```

Comment: This is for discord.js `14.6.0`

Comment: I tryed this, but I still dont get any reply or output in the console